# How to black box all the script files except the file you are debugging?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a nodejs code in chrome devtool
by the
 `node --inspect-brk app.js`  command.

While debugging the debugger most of the time getting into node's internal core modules . I know this can be avoided by black boxing the script file.

**But i want to know is there a way to black box all the script files except the file you are debugging in one go ?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Chrome blackboxing support regular express for the file name. Simply use the a Negative Lookahead `(?!your script)`.
eg. `^((?!myscript).)*$` will blackboxing any other script except myscript

Comment: What should i write if i want my only main.js to be available for debugging ?